# OpenLDAP user record insertion for authentication

Tags: openldap

I installed Open Ldap for windows in windows XP
i want to Insert user information in Open Ldap.
I don't now how to insert user information(like uid,mail,sn,password..etc). 
I tried with LDAP Admin Tool but it's not working.

Is that i need to change something in Slapd.conf file as well as LDIF file...
 can any one suggest any tutorial that will help me out of this

thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some tooling like [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) to edit contents on your ldap server in a GUI environment.

OpenLDAP is really good with textfiles too.

You can checkout the [quickstart guide](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html) for more links to information.